# Unlink .txt file every 2 hours

Tags: php

I was looking at the PHP site and found the "unlink" script:

what I want is a time to automatically unlink my "usernames.txt" file every 2 hours

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.
Create `unlinker.php` with contents

```
<?PHP
unlink('usernames.txt');
?>
```

and create a `cron` to execute that file every two hours.

By the way, that code is *example code*. you **shouldn't** use it at production

Comment: Hey, how do I create a "corn"? I am sorry I am new to php :)

Comment: There are a lot of answers in StackOverflow. Check http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+cron

Comment: But the easiest way to do it is through _cPanell_ (if your host use it). There is a function called `cronjobs` inside it

Comment: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs <- Documentation on CronJobs for cPanel

Comment: If your host is *nix, you can create cron via SSH with command `crontab`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```
$current_time = time();
$last_deleted = 0;    

if (file_exists("time.txt") {
    $last_deleted = file_get_contents("time.txt");

    if ($current_time - $last_deleted >= 7200) { // two hours
        file_put_contents("time.txt", $current_time);
        unlink("usernames.txt");
    }
}
else
    file_put_contents("time.txt", $current_time);
```

Comment: What do I have to put in time.txt?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it will check if file have been changed only when that script is called. It may `a) not be called for more time than the 2 expected hours, creating very big logs` or `b) add unnecessary overhead to your scripts if you execute that logic on every script`

Comment: @jgabriel yes, I realize that. But 1) it's easier and 2) it doesn't require anything but PHP. I didn't even think it was possible to run a script automatically until I saw your answer! :)

Comment: @user3184573 the code I've given already writes the file properly. (I'm writing a timestamp to the file.) All you need to do is copy-paste this stuff.